# How to Move appdata file to d disc

Tags: windows, cmd, mklink

I need to `mklink /J` Unity folder from `appdata` to `D:` disk.

Like this:

`C:\Users\hextechdolboeb\AppData\LocalLow\Unity` linked to `D:\Limbus Company\Unity`.

I try and get this error:

> ```
> "Cannot create a file when that file already exists."
> ```

command:

```bash
mklink /J "C:\Users\hextechdolboeb\AppData\LocalLow\Unity" "D:\Limbus_Company\Unity"
```

I just try it, no more.

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around:

```
mklink [[/d] | [/h] | [/j]] <link> <target>
```

So if you want a link to your AppData\LocalLow\ it has to be the target.

```
mklink /J "D:\Limbus_Company\Unity" "C:\Users\hextechdolboeb\AppData\LocalLow\Unity"
```